# Run Lisp functions on load

Tags: function, load, lisp

Whenever I (load "program.lisp") using the following code I get the error: "Error: Unexpected end of #input stream "program.lisp"

```
(defun theProgram () 
    (reset)
    (print "Hello Kappa")
    (setentries)
    (startloop)
    (loop for x in mylist collect (splitremove))
    (loop for x in numlist collect (getgrades))
    (loop for x in namelist collect (getprint))
    (loop for x in printlist collect (andprint)))
(theProgram)
```

I know the last line is the problem and it will work fine if it is not included however I need the program to startup on load, how can I achieve this?

Edit: I should note that setentries calls a (read) and so does startloop. I am using GNU common lisp 2.6 with gcl interpreter.

Comment: How should we help you, when you don't tell us what Lisp you are using, what code this calls, ...?

Comment: Everything in the code works when the call of that function is removed. I can call that function after loading the file and it will be fine, so I didn't think it was relevant. I should note that setentries calls a (read) and so does startloop. GNU common lisp 2.6

Comment: That error means you have unbalanced parentheses in `program.lisp`. The code you posted doesn't have that problem, so there must be more to it that's causing the problem.

Comment: What's the point of all those `loop` calls? You're collecting things, but not saving them anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error was that the (read) part in the functions did not have stream declared so it was reading the input from the script as it was running rather than from the terminal.